# DataTables set default sorting while ordering is set to false

Tags: datatables, columnsorting

I'm trying to sort by a column in datatables, while having the sorting disabled.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "order": [3,'desc'],
    "ordering": false
});
```

Will try to be clear as possible by showcasing the issue in this example: http://live.datatables.net/focajayi/1/edit

As you can see, I'm trying to sort by Age in descending order, but it won't sort it, unless I set 'ordering' to true.

I'm aware that I can do this with hacks, or the prettiest solution that I know of so far, would be to remove the ordering attribute, and use the columnDefs instead, which seems to work as expected, but I would like to know if there's a global solution, without having to build the columnDefs data.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more research I found a close enough solution.
So what I've done, is just set the ordering to true, and then specifying it in the columnDefs.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "order": [3,'desc'],
    "ordering": true,
    "columnDefs": [{
      "targets": "_all", "orderable": false
    }]
});
```

Turns out it's possible to use the '_all' keyword to apply for all columns.
I was worried in always having to maintain the columnDefs list, but with the '_all' target it's perfect.